# Simple summation of a column that has its own formula in mdx

Tags: sql, mdx, multidimensional-cube

I have 3 measures: A, B, C

Measure c is this calculation:

```
IF(A>B) 
  THEN A-B
ELSE 0
```

This formula run for every records, which works fine. The problem is that.
I want to get sum of the measure c, the above formula work.

> ```
>          A   B   C
>          5   2   3
>          6   8   0
> total : 11  10   1
> ```

In above example the result that shown is "1" But I want to show "3"

What I want is this :

> ```
>          A   B   C
>          5   2   3
>          6   8   0
> total : 11  10   3
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the formula was running in the SUM too.
See:

```
total : 11  10   1
```

11 is greater than 10, and 1 is 11-10;

Your formula are been applied

```
IF(A>B) 
  THEN A-B
ELSE 0
```

Try to make a query with different statement.
Separating the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

So not and ideal answer, as this measure will be tied to the hierarchy you want on `ROWS`.

Lets imagine you want the measure specifically when you use `[Date]` on rows.

```
SUM(
DESCENDANTS(
  [Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER, 
  [Date].[Calendar].[Date]
)
, IIF(
    [Measures].[A] > [Measures].[B]
    , [Measures].[A] - [Measures].[B]
    , NULL 
  )
)
```