# Summing calculated measure for flat dimension

Tags: scope, sum, mdx

I have created a calculated measure, that I need the sum of in the grand total line, og when no dimension is selected.
Until now, I have tried various methods, all of them ending in either wrong result or blank grand total.

The calculation is to select one measure over another. If the first is <> 0, choose that else if the other is <> 0 choose that, else end with NULL.

This is my current code, in a script:

```
SCOPE ([Measures].[Output Quantity 3]);
    SCOPE ([Production Order No].[Production Order No].MEMBERS);
        THIS =
            IIF([Measures].[MC Output Quantity]<>0,
                [Measures].[MC Output Quantity],
                IIF([Measures].[PO Output Quantity]<>0,
                    [Measures].[PO Output Quantity],
                    NULL
                )
            );
    END SCOPE;
END SCOPE;
```

Implemented after reading this article by Chriss Webb: [https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2013/05/29/aggregating-the-result-of-an-mdx-calculation-using-scoped-assignments/](https://stackoverflow.com)

It does the trick on the line level, but repeats the same calculation/comparison on grand total.

Adding a level in the second SCOPE, like this:

```
SCOPE ([Measures].[Output Quantity 3]);
    SCOPE ([Production Order No].[Production Order No].**[Production Order No]**.MEMBERS);
        THIS =
            IIF([Measures].[MC Output Quantity]<>0,
                [Measures].[MC Output Quantity],
                IIF([Measures].[PO Output Quantity]<>0,
                    [Measures].[PO Output Quantity],
                    NULL
                )
            );
    END SCOPE;
END SCOPE;
```

Results in a blank grand total.

Other solutions have used calculation in measures instead of scope. I do not mind which one solves the problem.

I believe the issue is the same as described in this question: [Simple summation of a column that has its own formula in mdx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75374658/6326163)
Just that I do not have hierarchies in my dimension(s).
Also, I did not fully understand the answer *"Try to make a query with different statement. Separating the conditions."*